# Achartengine X labels with uneven interval of time

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using TimeChartView of AChartEngine 0.7.0 to draw chart.

on x-axis there is date and for y-axis there is value for specific date.
i am parsing these values from xml so someday I get value of complete last 5 day but someday only of 3 days so when i get value of 3 days, chart shows x-values shifted compared to y-values. also sometimes there is repetition of date due to fix number of x-labels which i have solved.

I think i have similar problem to this [SO Quest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6576164/626481) and mostly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6176822/626481) as I want to set X-intervals by using dates.

[image: MyChart]

Here Originally from XML,I am having values of date 28.09,27.09,26.09 but it displays as above.

Answer (score 0):

When the number of (x,y) values are changed suppose from 5 to 3 or vice versa you should first remove the values that repaint the chart

```
public XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
dataset.getSeriesAt(0).clear(); // use this to clear your data set
dataset.getSeriesAt(0).add(x, y) // use this to add the new x,y values
```

Comment: but i am defining series first and then assigning :

 for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) {
    series.add(xV[k].getTime(), yV[k]);
   }
   
   dataset.addSeries(series);

Comment: Here you add a new series every time when there is a change in data. But the old series are remain into the dataset. If you make update in series then you should either follow the approach which I provide to you or at first remove the series for dataset then add new series as you do

Comment: Give me the answer of one question. Suppose you have run your app for the first time and draw chart for 3 values. Is that time chart show correct graph. If the answer is yes then you follow my approach and it will be perfect.